# how to change contact page address in joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I have a joomla site which is developed and designed by someone else. I need to change the address on connect with us page.

I checked in main menu and found connect with us menu item and item type is Contact Us Form. But there is no article related to this. No modules, No plugin and no contacts in components.

I don't know from where I can change address of connect with us page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do the changes you need to go to,

> Components-> Contacts-> Contacts

There you'll find the option that needs to be changed.

Comment: There is no option contacts in components dropdown. The user is super user

Comment: You are using which version of joomla

Comment: Please check this [url](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/joomla25/joomla25-contact-us-page.htm) .Even if you are using joomla 2.5 or 1.7 there's a option.

Comment: using joomla 2.5 and I checked the components menu there is no contacts menu

Comment: @dreamer Have you checked the url, which I mentioned above ?

Comment: Yes checked the same. But I am working on production instance and there is 2 address on contact us page. I just need to update the addresses. The item type for this menu is Contact Us Form from forms menu. there is one more form which is book an appointment form.

Comment: Is there any other extension for the form. @dreamer, can you just share menu item screenshot here, that is being selected

Comment: here it is http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/834299/8410935f8086f9fea651715a349b3b5b

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97833/discussion-between-nehal-and-dreamer).